# onclick event with div tag

Tags: html

I tried something with div tag as follows,

```
  <style type="text/css">
    #hello{
        visibility: visible;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #list{
        visibility: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        z-index:  1;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    #second{
            position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<div id="hello" onclick="{if(list.style.visibility=='hidden'){list.style.visibility='visible';}else{list.style.visibility='hidden'};}">Hello user</div><br/>
      <div id="second">Welcome to smartdata</div>
      <div id="list">
          <a href="index.jsp">Home</a> <br/>
          <a href="#" onclick="{alert('You are going to signout');}">SignOut</a> <br/>
      </div>
```

It is working fine but the problem is list is not displaying on the first click. Any thing wrong with my code.??

Comment: A side note: you don't need to wrap your event handlers in curly braces. They are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as you expect it to due to the way `element.style` works.

Check this MDN link on element.style: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style

> Since the style property has the same (and highest) priority in the
>   CSS cascade as an inline style declaration via the style attribute, it
>   is useful for setting style on one specific element.
>
> However, it is not useful for learning about the element's style in
>   general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the
>   element's **inline style attribute, not those that come from style
>   rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the  section, or
>   external style sheets**.

So when you first run your code and even if your `element.style.hidden` is declared in the *external* CSS sheet, the style declaration remains empty and you need to perform additional checks.

```
if (!list.style.visibility || list.style.visibility === 'hidden') {...}
```

You can take a look at the fiddle to see it work: http://jsfiddle.net/Kk6TJ/1/

**Also:**

1. It's best to use triple equal `===` to perform strict comparison without converting variable type.
2. You don't need curly braces in your event handlers. If you were hoping that they would create scope - they don't! Only functions in JavaScript have scope.

Answer (score 2):

`list.style.visibility=='hidden'` is a false statement on first click

try this

```
{if(list.style.visibility=='hidden' || list.style.visibility='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #hello{
        visibility: visible;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #list{
        visibility: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        z-index:  1;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    #second{
            position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<div id="hello" onclick="{if(list.style.visibility=='hidden' || list.style.visibility==''){list.style.visibility='visible';}else{list.style.visibility='hidden'};}">Hello user</div><br/>
      <div id="second">Welcome to smartdata</div>
      <div id="list">
          <a href="index.jsp">Home</a> <br/>
          <a href="#" onclick="{alert('You are going to signout');}">SignOut</a> <br/>
      </div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your if..else are not in order. Re-ordering of decision statement corrected the behavior, Now first click is showing the menu items.

Also, If you run your script and watch it in firebug console you'll see your javascript code is throwing warning on first click.

[image]

I've updated your code -

```
     <style type="text/css">
    #hello{
        visibility: visible;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #list{
        visibility: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        z-index:  1;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    #second{
            position: absolute;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Clickme()
{
var list = document.getElementById('list');

if(list.style.visibility=='visible')
{
list.style.visibility='hidden';
}
else
{
list.style.visibility='visible'
}
}
</script>
<div id="hello" onclick="Clickme();">Hello user</div><br/>
      <div id="second">Welcome to smartdata</div>
      <div id="list">
          <a href="index.jsp">Home</a> <br/>
          <a href="#" onclick="{alert('You are going to signout');}">SignOut</a> <br/>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles defined in style tags and css files are not in the element.style.property property, they are available if the element has its style set inline `<element style="property:value;">` or explicitly `element.style.property = value;`

To get styles for an element defined in style tags/sheets use window.[getComputedStyle](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle)(element, null).[getPropertyValue](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration-getPropertyValue)(property);`

So you can either inline the styles on list, use getComputedStyle getPropertyValue or use the fact that `list.style.visibility` is going to be empty on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

Go for something like this -

```
if(list.style.visibility=="visible")
{
   list.style.visibility="hidden";
}
else
{
   list.style.visibility="visible"
}
```